Creating a development server in Angular has error :TS2502
I have created a angular application with the following versions.
Angular CLI: 14.2.13
Node: 16.20.2
Package Manager: npm 8.19.4
When I created a new angular project.
And run the project as development server using "ng serve" command.
I get this issue.
Error: node_modules/@types/node/stream/web.d.ts:459:13 - error TS2502: 'ReadableByteStreamController' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.

459         var ReadableByteStreamController: typeof globalThis extends
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@types/node/stream/web.d.ts:468:13 - error TS2502: 'ReadableStreamBYOBReader' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.

468         var ReadableStreamBYOBReader: typeof globalThis extends { onmessage: any; ReadableStreamBYOBReader: infer T }
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@types/node/stream/web.d.ts:473:13 - error TS2502: 'ReadableStreamBYOBRequest' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.

473         var ReadableStreamBYOBRequest: typeof globalThis extends { onmessage: any; ReadableStreamBYOBRequest: infer T }

I cleared this error with another stack overflow question
new new creates corrupt project
<--I had the same issue and just solved it in the following way. Set the skipLibCheck flag to true in the angularCompilerOptions inside your tsconfig.json file.-->
But it is not helping me to fix globally.
I have to skipLIbcheck every time with this fix.
Help me to fix it whenever I create the angular app.

Like with the question that you referenced, your error output would be more legible if it were delimited with triple-back-ticks.

I notice this comment from Miki Noidea, It won't only tell compiler to skip d.ts type checking in code that you can not control (i.e. node_modules), but instead it skips all d.ts files. Can you rename affected files such they all have the same name to avoid checking?

I have the same issue.  Have you resolved it?  Thank you
